# How to transform nanometer/transmittance csv dataset into RGB values for a LUT?

Tags: csv, colors, cube

I have a single curve wavelength graph chart with x/y plot points of nanometers (x) / Diffuse Density or Transmittance% (y). I have it as a table. How would I then engineer this data to produce RGB curves which would recreate the overall colour? My end goal is to produce a linear to log 3d lut cube. It's only for an approximation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My data is from 400 nm to 700nm (the visible spectrum) and is as follows:-

[csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPkJa.png)

I'm looking for a method to read the csv table, column 1 is nanometres wavelength and column 2 is transmittance. Im trying to  produce a split RGB curve that reflects the data in the chart csv table converted to CIE 1964/then RGB values. I want to eventually make it into a LUT to reflect the colours affected by transmittance for a recreation of a Kodak photographic filter - in this case an amber filter  - and to show how much transmittance each color accepts in a curve cube to effect a colour image.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour):

```py
import colour
# Using gaussian distribution reshaped to a uniform distribution with the 400-700nm shape and 1nm interval:
sd_transmittance = colour.sd_gaussian(650, 50).align(colour.SpectralShape(400, 700, 1))
colour.plotting.plot_single_sd(sd_transmittance)
# Transmitting using "CIE Standard Illuminant D65" as the "light source".
# The output is relative percentage, thus dividing by 100 to get a value in range [0, 1]:
XYZ = colour.sd_to_XYZ(sd_transmittance, illuminant=colour.SDS_ILLUMINANTS["D65"]) / 100
# Direct conversion from "CIE XYZ" tristimulus values to linear "sRGB":
colour.XYZ_to_sRGB(XYZ)
```

```
array([ 0.96628694,  0.36616433, -0.38398073])
```

Note how the output colour has negative blue component, meaning that the *sRGB* colourspace cannot reproduce it.

[image: 650nm - 50 Sigma - Gaussian]